# changing css class name according to screensize and then giving style to that class only on 'onload'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

The site I am working on is http://ikkurty.ewsdev.in/objective/ . It is a WordPress site (Avada theme) which is working fine. The move up effect which I am using in this site is with help of this JS:

```
window.onload = function()
{
var size = -500;
document.getElementById("sliders-container").style.marginTop = size + "px";
};
```

and this css

```
#sliders-container{
transition: 5s;
}
```

but when I check the site in different responsive layouts the Image move up too much and the image cannot be seen any more. I want the image to be seen a little not completely vanished so I tried this JS:

```
window.onload = function()
        {   
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            if(windowWidth > 768){
            var size = -500;
            }
            document.getElementById("sliders-container").style.marginTop = size + "px";

        };
```

but it is not working at all. I actually want to change the `var size` according to screen size. I am new to JavaScript and I am here to learn.

Comment: Why use JS? It would seem to make more sense to do this using CSS Media Queries - especially as you state you already have responsive layouts.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my guess would be JS was used, to get the transition triggered on page load. So that could easily be replaced by adding a class to the html or body element on page load, use that to trigger the transition, and use media queries to provide different margin-top values based on screen size.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe to understand what I actually want. Please help me with it or give me some another idea to achieve what is needed.

Comment: I _did_ just outline the idea in the previous comment ...

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries in CSS.

Try this:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: I know this very well. please open the link I gave and please try to understand what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like I wanted using this JS:

```
window.onload = function()
    {
        if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1280) {      
            document.getElementById('sliders-container').className = 'transition2';
        }
        else if ( jQuery(window).width() > 600 && jQuery(window).width() < 1280) {
            document.getElementById('sliders-container').className = 'transition3';
        }
        else if ( jQuery(window).width() < 600) {
            document.getElementById('sliders-container').className = 'transition4';
        }
        var size = -500;
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('transition2');
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.marginTop = size + "px";
        }
        var size = -360;
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('transition3');
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.marginTop = size + "px";
        }
        var size = -200;
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('transition4');
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.marginTop = size + "px";
        }
    };
```

Thank you @CBroe for the idea.

Comment: That was not really how it was meant though ... You should use _media queries_ in your CSS, to specify the margin-top value to apply for different screen sizes. `html.startMyAnimation #sliders-container { margin-top: 123px; }` - you repeat that inside different media queries, to specify the appropriate margin-top value for each screen size. And then you just add that class to the html element via JS when your page loads.